# how to add submit button to react-form-builder2

Tags: reactjs, forms, npm

I am using the npm package `react-form-builder2` in my React project,

```
import { ReactFormBuilder } from "react-form-builder2";
export default function builder() {
  return (
    <ReactFormBuilder />
  );
}
```

*I have also also added the necessary bootstrap and fontawsome in my index.html.*
[image: FormBuilder]

How do i add a **submit button** to this form such that when i press submit i get all the data present in the form builder?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might work:

```
<ReactFormBuilder
    data={form}
    onChange={handleUpdate}
    onPost={handleSubmit}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    actionName={"Set this to change the default submit button text"}
    submitButton={<button type={"submit"} className={"btn btn-primary"}>Submit</button>}
/>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this but did not work, anyways thank you :)

Comment: Can you tell what output you're getting?

Comment: It still looks like the photo i have added, i am not able to see any submit button.

Comment: That's great. If my answer has helped you in any way, please upvote and mark as Accepted Answer by clicking on the checkbox. I'm updating the answer with content onPost={handleSubmit}

Answer (score 0):

Use `ElementStore` which is already there in `_react-form-builder2_` to store the form value for a reference check.

```
useEffect(()=> {
 ElementStore.subscribe((state:any)=>onChange(state.data))
},[])
 const onChange = (data:any) => {
 console.log(data);
 setData(data);
}
```

Set the data in `React.useState` to submit your form fields to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today, the problem is that you are missing another component required to submit the generated form

the component is named as demoBar
check this for reference : https://codesandbox.io/s/rfb-cra-4w1le?file=/src/index.js:370-403